# Certbot generates certificate using DST Root CA X3

Tags: ssl, centos7, certbot

I have a CentOS 7 machine where I am running httpd. I want to install a Letsencrypt certificate. I am using the following:
`certbot certonly --standalone -d sub.domain.com`

Which generates the certificate and saves it to:

- /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/fullchain.pem
- /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/privkey.pem

In my httpd configuration I am specifying the following:

```sh
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/privkey.pem
```

When I browse to https://sub.domain.com I am getting an error that the certificate is not valid (due to expiration).

I have checked the certificate with `openssl`:

```sh
openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/fullchain.pem -noout -text
```

Output:

```sh
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=R3
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 15 09:48:49 2021 GMT
            Not After : Mar 15 09:48:48 2022 GMT

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://r3.o.lencr.org
                CA Issuers - URI:http://r3.i.lencr.org/
```

So the certificate itself is not expired, but the intermediate Root X3 is expired, but why is the Root X3 certificate still being used?

My `ca-certificates` package is up to date (`ca-certificates-2021.2.50-72.el7_9.noarch`).

`/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` does not contain the `Root X3` anymore. It does contain the `ISRG Root X1` certificate.

What am I mising?

Comment: Have you tried to restart httpd?

Comment: @kometen: Yes, httpd is restarted.

Comment: What version of Certbot are you running?

Comment: @Lamar: Package certbot-1.11.0-2.

Comment: Same issue, did you resolved it @C-nan ?